# Project with socket.io, express, and nodejs getting error: "during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

So I'm working on an online multiplier game that has a lobby system through socket.io. The lobby system allows users to join and leave games, all of which is managed by socket.io. When I test the site on localhost it works fine, but when I put the project on the web, I run into an issue that doesn't allow users to leave and join rooms smoothly like before.

When the user sends a POST request to join a lobby, I use ejs to render the lobby html with a file called lobby.ejs that has the following relevant code:

```
    <script> let lobby = <%- JSON.stringify(data.lobby) %>; let name = <%- JSON.stringify(data.name) %></script>
    <script src="./js/ejs/ejs.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/lobby.js"></script>
```

in lobby.js, I do:
`const socket = io()`

Here's what's relevant on the server side in my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
var bp = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

var server = require('http').createServer(app)

var urlEncodedParser = bp.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('views'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {qs: req.query})
})

app.post('/lobby', urlEncodedParser, (req, res) => {
    res.render('lobby', {data: req.body})
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    //console.log('server started')
})

var io = require('socket.io')(server)
```

The issue is that whenever a user enter's a lobby, and i make the socket connection with `const socket = io()`
I get the handshake error. Then when the user closes out of the tab, the player list isn't updated in the lobby for every other user (this worked on localhost without an issue).

I get that the 400 error means the server got something from the client request it couldn't understand or didn't like but I'm not sure what that could be when it worked fine on localhost.

If there's any important information I left out please let me know. This is my first time posting a question so I'm not too familiar with best practices yet.

Comment: In the website environment, is it using `http` or `https`? If `https`, how was the certificate generated? Is there layer between the server and client? Sometimes there are servers (Apache, Nginx, ...) or caching tools like Varnish, etc. All of these things could be interacting with the Socket request.

Comment: @Ignacio, in the website environment it's an http connection. I'm using gcloud to host the website, and now you've got me wondering if maybe their server could be affected the socket connection?